# KiCad missing footprints after update

Tags: kicad

Today I updated my KiCad by installing new version over the previous one.
Afterwars I created a new project, added schematic symbols, associated them to footprints and generated netlist.
Now when I'm trying to read netlist in Pcbnew I get errors about missing `TO-220-3_Vertical` footprint. This footprint was available in the previous version of KiCad and should be in the default github library.

What is going on? Am I doing something wrong?

The full error is:

```
Error: Component “U1” footprint “TO-220-3_Vertical” was not found in any libraries in the footprint library table. 
Error: Cannot add new symbol “U1:/5B6DC52C” due to missing footprint “Package_TO_SOT_THT:TO-220-3_Vertical”.
```

When I was assigning footprints to symbols I could see correct footprints in the preview window.

Comment: https://forum.kicad.info/t/fixing-footprint-library-path-4-0-0-rc2/1736/10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 5.0 update changed the names of a lot of the libraries. You can either delete the old libraries so they stop giving you errors and just use the new ones (most of the footprints are still there, but under more descriptive names) or you can [download the old 4.0 libraries here](https://www.kicad.org/libraries/download/) and re-add them.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by @Darius there could also be a different problem at play.

If you had version 4 installed in the past then you might have ended up with a mixture of different library versions. In a typical installation your fp-lib-table will not be overwritten with the version 5 entries (you will still have the old on demand online libs active.) but the symbols and 3d models are installed from version 5.
This means that the symbols (which are designed to work with version 5 footprints) will not have the correct footprint in the library.

More details see my post in the kicad forum: https://forum.kicad.info/t/i-had-kicad-4-installed-previosly-now-i-updated-to-v5-now-i-have-some-problems-with-the-library-setup/11932

---

I would not suggest the use of the version 4 library for new projects as it will be no longer maintained. (this means the longer you wait with the transfer to the new library the harder it will get for you)